# React Js How do you call the same functions from two React Redux Fields?

Tags: reactjs

Component method gets called for both Title and Content fields when React is initially rendered. However, while additional input change in Title field calls the renderField method, the Content field doesn't seem to do so. This is reflected in the console log where the initial component load produced 2 "input changed" and for additional changes in the title, "input change" prints, but no responses occur when changes are made to the content field. What's going on?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class PostNew extends Component {

    renderField(field) {
        console.log('input changed')
        return(
            <div>
                <label>{field.label}</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    {...field.input}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <form>
                <Field
                    label="Title"
                    name="title"
                    component={this.renderField}
                />
                <Field
                    label="Content"
                    name="content"
                    component={this.renderField}
                />
            </form>
        )
    }
}


export default reduxForm({
    form: 'PostsNewForm' // form property is the name of the form
})(PostNew);
```

Comment: I pasted your renderField and render methods into my React project and it worked for both. Not sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: Could you try it in this project? https://github.com/datumsays/React-Redux-Error

Comment: It's the pretty much the same code. I'm wondering if this is a package issue.

Comment: I'm downloading your project right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was able to replicate your issue. The problem is that redux-form isn't just plug and play. You need to add it into your root reducer as shown below:

```
//src/reducers/index.js

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import {reducer as form} from 'redux-form';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  state: (state = {}) => state,
  form
});

export default rootReducer;
```

The form fields work as expected for me once I added that. I've uploaded a copy of your Github project with a working example:

https://github.com/hellojebus/so-Answer

Comment: Okay. Let me try your suggestion

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't work. One thing I want to note though is that in either cases I do get an error saying the following: "bundle.js:1212 Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded "

Comment: Though I've been ignoring it since I was still able to make method call when changing the title input.

Comment: A javascript error will cause your code to stop executing, so we will need to handle that issue before moving forward. Make sure you are not referencing React twice in any of your files.

Comment: Also, are you using refs in your code at all? I don't see any in the github link you posted.

Comment: I'm not. This is such a perplexing problem. I can't wrap my head around what's wrong with it at all. I'm also positive that I'm not calling React twice.

Comment: Can you download my project, it is a working example with your code: https://github.com/hellojebus/so-Answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145294/discussion-between-mlhacker-and-hellojebus).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encountered a similar issue as mine. The source of the problem ultimately came from the fact that the redux-form package didn't install at all. So either use yarn install redux-form or try npm but ensure check that npm works.